# Return 0 as integer not bool

Tags: javascript

I have a function where if successful, it returns an integer, but if not it just returns `false`.

Here's part of my code:

```
    function hellofunc(x) {
//....

        if (returnvalue.length == 1) {
            return returnvalue[0];
        } else if (returnvalue.length > 1) {
            return returnvalue[rx(0, returnvalue.length - 1)];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When the function calls this -> `return returnvalue[0];` it gives `0` as an integer.

But when I call `hellofunc(something);` I see it writes to console "0" but when I type something false it returns `false`,

JavaScript thinks `0` is `false`? So what do I do here? Do I do this?

```
hellofunc(something)!==false
```

Or is there any better solution?

Comment: Do you have numbers in the `returnvalue` array, and if so, how would you want the numbers to be interpreted as booleans? Which numbers should end up as `true` and which should end up as `false`?

Comment: Yep, JavaScript considers `0` to be `false` or "falsey" as people say. Any value can be substituted for a boolean condition. Other "falsey" values are `null`, `undefined`, `NaN` and `""`.

Comment: I'm not sure what your function does but best practices suggest that your function should always return the same data type.  If you return an integer on success, the typical return on failure is negative one. E.g. return -1;  see the String.indexOf(str); as a good example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hellofunc(something) !== false
```

as you said..no better solution..:)

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages 0 is false. It comes from the representation of a number in binary. Since in the boolean logic you only have 2 choices - True and False, you only need one bit to represent that. 1 for True and 0 for False.